Why does the SUSY algebra only close off-shell?
Consider a supersymmetric theory with action $S$.
When computing anti-commutators of supersymmetric transformations $\delta_\epsilon$, one would find that,
$$ \{ \delta_{\epsilon_1}, \delta_{\epsilon_2} \} (\mathrm{field}) = \delta_B (\mathrm{field}) + \mathrm{e.o.m.} $$
where $\mathrm{e.o.m.}$ only vanishes on-shell and $\delta_B$ is some combination of bosonic generators of the theory. This suggests that the SUSY algebra only closes on-shell. However, since the action is supersymmetric invariant (even off-shell !),
$$ \delta_{\epsilon} S = 0 \implies \{ \delta_{\epsilon_1}, \delta_{\epsilon_2} \} S = 0 $$
The operation $ \{ \delta_{\epsilon_1}, \delta_{\epsilon_2} \}$ is bosonic, and the last equation is the definition of a bosonic symmetry. So, it should be that
$$ \{ \delta_{\epsilon_1}, \delta_{\epsilon_2} \} = \delta_B $$
even off-shell. Where is this argument wrong ?

Are you sure the action invariant off-shell?

Yes. You can have a look at equations (2.11) and (2.15) in the book "Modern Supersymmetry ..." by John Terring. He only uses that the boundary term vanishes at infinity

Ignoring the boundary terms at infinity seems to precisely be the problem.

It doesn't change the fact that ${ \delta_{\epsilon_1} ,\delta_{\epsilon_2} }$ should be a symmetry after integrating over space-time. Also, I checked that it is indeed a symmetry of the action. I think it is simply that the structure is not nice, because it doesn't properly act on fermions, e.g. ${\delta_{\epsilon_1}, \delta_{\epsilon_2}} \psi_\alpha \sim (\epsilon_1)_\alpha (\mathrm{e.o.m})$. The equations of motions simply involve derivatives which are the momentum, so it's indeed part of the bosonic generators. But the variations parameters don't factorize so the algebra doesn't close.
